# Spring MVC how to return to same view on login failed

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-java-config

I have Spring Security configured as:

```
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
{
    http
        .csrf().disable()
        .formLogin()
            .successHandler( successHandler() )
            .loginPage("/login")
            .loginProcessingUrl("/loginProcess")
            .failureUrl( LOGIN_ERROR )}
```

How would be my controller for LOGIN_ERROR path in order to keep the user into same page but showing the expected error on login form?

And could be posible redirect user to Registration page when user failed to login 3 times?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first question's answer:

1. You can create a "CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler" by extending the  `AuthenticationFailureHandler` class.
2. In `CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler`'s `onAuthenticationFailure` method, write this code:

   ```
   @Override
   public void onAuthenticationFailure(HttpServletRequest request,
           HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException exception)
           throws IOException, ServletException
   {
       saveException(request, exception);
       redirectStrategy.sendRedirect(request, response, request.getHeader("referer"));
   }
   ```
3. In your configuration file add this code instead of `failureUrl`:

   ```
   @Bean
   public CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler customAuthenticationFailureHandler()
   {
       return new CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler();
   }

   http.failureHandler(customAuthenticationFailureHandler())
   ```

Your second question's answer:

You can use a session or database to store failure attempts. Then after 3 failure attempts, you just need to change the url to redirect.

Answer (score 0):

The common way is to return to the login page(`failureUrl( "/login?error" )`) and in the login form view:

```
<c:if test="${not empty error}">
    <div class="error">${error}</div>
</c:if>
```

That way when you navigate to login the first time error parameter will be empty the the error message will not be shown.

Comment: I have no a login page, instead user can log in on any part of my website via modal window